# How to convert hex string to color image in python?

Tags: python, image, hex, python-imaging-library

i'm new in programming so i have some question about converting string to color image.

i have one data , it consists of Hex String, like a fff2f3.....
i want to convert this file to png like this.

[image]

i can convert the hex data to png image through  [this site](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en)
but i don't know how to convert the hex data to png image using python code 
but i tried to use `Image.frombytes('RGB',(1600,1059),hex_str)` but 
i don't know image size , so i cannot use this method.

so My question is how can i convert this hex [data](https://github.com/SoulDuck/tmp_repository/blob/master/binary_file) to image using python code

please give me some advise , thank you :)

Comment: How many pixels are in the data?  Knowing the number of pixels might help figuring out the heighth and width ... `H * W == number_of_pixels`.

Comment: If there are 65536 characters in the string and the image is `'RGBA'` then there are 8 characters per pixel which would be 8192 pixels - so maybe the image size is  128x64 or 256x32 ...

Comment: Why don't you know the image size?

Comment: @wwii thanks for comment, I don't think ,the image size is 128x64 or 256x32 , becuase when i recover image from string using the web program that i mentioned above, the image size is 600 x 1590, so my question is how  web program that convert string to image can know image size , even my string file is broken , thank you

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams thank you for comments , because i just have string file and my files almost broken , so i don't know the image size exactly,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading the hexadecimal string into a bytes object, and then writing that binary into a `.png` file can be done like this:

```
with open('binary_file') as file:
    data = file.read()

data = bytes.fromhex(data[2:])

with open('image.png', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

And produces this result, keep in mind it is corrupted:

[image: corrupted result]

Comment: I know this old, but I just wanted to add that `.strip()` fixed my ended issue. I was importing text from a text editor that enjoyed making subtle changes to the raw file, including an extra \n at end (Atom editor).

Comment: @Alistair: Does this work the same way in C?

Comment: @coder101 Yes, there is nothing language specific about the solution. It will have to be translated, of course.